# How is the function $\int^{\infty}_x e^{ipx'} dx'$related to the dirac delta function?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

The function in question is defined to be $\int^{\infty}_x e^{ipx'} dx'$ It must be a function of $x$ and $p$ and related to the delta function. But I cannot figure out how the $x$ influneces the function....Could anyone please help me?

Comment: x-posted on Physics.SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/403544/84967

Answer (score 1):

The integral does not converge in ordinary sense, but it can be understood as distribution. Its behavior is easier to track if we choose a suitable regularization. Indeed, for $\epsilon > 0$

\begin{align*}
\int_{x}^{\infty} e^{ipx'}e^{-\epsilon x'}\,dx'
&= \frac{1}{\epsilon - ip} e^{(ip-\epsilon)x} \\
&= \underbrace{ \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2 + p^2} e^{(ip-\epsilon)x} }_{(1)} + \underbrace{ \frac{ip}{\epsilon^2 + p^2} e^{(ip-\epsilon)x} }_{(2)}.
\end{align*}

We can show that its distribution limit as $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ is

$$ ``\int_{x}^{\infty} e^{ipx'} \,dx' \,\text{''} = \pi \delta(p) + \frac{i}{p}e^{ipx}. $$

More precisely, we can prove that

> **Claim.** For each test function $\varphi\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ we have
>
> $$ \lim_{\epsilon\downarrow 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{x}^{\infty} e^{ipx'}e^{-\epsilon x'}\,dx'\right) \varphi(p) \, dp
> = \pi \varphi(0) + \mathrm{PV}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{i}{p}e^{ipx}\varphi(p) \, dp. $$

Indeed, for $\text{(1)}$ we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2 + p^2} e^{(ip-\epsilon)x} \right) \varphi(p) \, dp
&\stackrel{p\mapsto \epsilon p}{=} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{1+p^2} e^{\epsilon(ip-1)x} \varphi(\epsilon p) \, dp \\
&\xrightarrow[\epsilon\downarrow0]{} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{1+p^2} \varphi(0) \, dp
= \pi \varphi(0)
\end{align*}

by the dominated convergence theorem with the dominating function $\frac{1}{1+p^2}e^{-x}\|\varphi\|_{\infty}$. For $\text{(2)}$, we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \frac{ip}{\epsilon^2 + p^2} e^{(ip-\epsilon)x} \right) \varphi(p) \, dp
&= e^{-\epsilon x} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{ip}{\epsilon^2 + p^2} \left( \frac{e^{ipx} \varphi(p) - e^{-ipx} \varphi(-p)}{2} \right) \, dp \\
&\xrightarrow[\epsilon\downarrow0]{} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{i}{p} \left( \frac{e^{ipx} \varphi(p) - e^{-ipx} \varphi(-p)}{2} \right) \, dp \\
&= \mathrm{PV} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{i}{p} e^{ipx} \varphi(p) \, dp,
\end{align*}

again the convergence follows from the dominated convergence theorem with the dominating function $\frac{1}{2p}\left| e^{ipx} \varphi(p) - e^{-ipx} \varphi(-p) \right|$, which is a compactly-supported continuous function thanks to removable singularity. (This hints why we take only odd part of $e^{ipx} \varphi(p)$ before taking limit.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think it is $-i/pe^{ipx}$ instead of $i/pe^{ipx}$ in your limit as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: @Keith, I am not sure what led you to think so. If you agree with $$\int_{x}^{\infty} e^{ipx'}e^{-\epsilon x'}\,dx' = \frac{1}{\epsilon - ip} e^{(ip-\epsilon)x} = \frac{\epsilon+ip}{\epsilon^2 + p^2} e^{(ip-\epsilon)x}$$ then it is quite straightforward to see that the limit will involve $+\frac{i}{p}e^{ipx}$. (And although software computation does not comprise a proof, you can also check this answer in *Mathematica* by executing the command `FourierTransform[HeavisideTheta[y - x], y, p, 
 FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]`.)

Comment: Oh I got confused. I got mixed up with the reciprocal of i. Yes your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Another way to introduce the [suggested @Sangchul Lee regularization](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2763904/85343) is to use a *Fourier Representation* of the *Heaviside Step Function*
>   $\ds{\mrm{H}: \mathbb{R}\setminus\braces{0} \to \mathbb{R}}$. 
>   
>    Namely, $\ds{\mrm{H}\pars{x} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic kx} \over k - \ic 0^{+}}\,{\dd k \over 2\pi\ic}}$.

\begin{align}
\int_{x}^{\infty}\expo{\ic px'}\dd x' & =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mrm{H}\pars{x' - x}\expo{\ic px'}\dd x' =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bracks{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic k\pars{x' - x}} \over k - \ic 0^{+}}\,{\dd k \over 2\pi\ic}}\expo{\ic px'}\dd x'
\\[5mm] &=
-\ic\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{-\ic kx} \over k - \ic 0^{+}}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic\pars{k + p}x'}{\dd x' \over 2\pi}\,\dd k =
-\ic\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{-\ic kx} \over k - \ic 0^{+}}\,
\delta\pars{k + p}\,\dd k
\\[5mm] & =
-\ic\,{\expo{\ic px} \over -p - \ic 0^{+}} =
\ic\expo{\ic px}\bracks{\mrm{P.V.}{1 \over p} -\ic\pi\,\delta\pars{p}} =
\bbx{\ic\,\mrm{P.V.}{\expo{\ic px} \over p} + \pi\,\delta\pars{p}}
\end{align}
which means
$$
\bbx{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi\pars{p}
\pars{\int_{x}^{\infty}\expo{\ic px'}\dd x'}\dd p =
\ic\,\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\varphi\pars{p} \over p}
\,\expo{\ic px}\dd p + \pi\varphi\pars{0}}
$$
as *fully* explained in the above cited link.